# DCount/Checking if value exists in Access DB field

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a form which users fill out for new clients for our company. The ID is manually assigned because it's a composite of the year `E18` for example this year, and a 5 digit number. So `E1800001` could be one client. I'm in the process of automating this. I have the code to automate the number assignment, however because multiple people can be using it at the same time, we ran into a situation where two people got the same number, and the ran into a duplicate error. I've now included another code that will check the assigned number in the case that someone beat them to it using `DCount`, but it is not working and giving me:

> RT error 2471. "the expression you entered as a query parameter produces this error:"

Here is my code:

```
Dim countNumber as Integer
Dim lookupNumber as Variant

lookupnumber = Me!Master_ClientNumber
countNumber = DCount("[Client Name]", "Master Client List", "[Client Number]= " & lookupNumber)

If countNumber > 0 Then
   MsgBox "That number is taken."
Else
   MsgBox "This number is free."
End If
```

Comment: There's isn't a closing bracket on the end of `DCOUNT` - but that's probably just a typo.  Try `"[Client Number]= '" & lookupNumber & "'")` (treat `lookupNumber` as text)

Comment: Are you generating this ID before the user is inputs the information for the new customer (not a good idea), or is it generated after all the data is entered and the new record is being saved to the database (this is better)? I would suggest using an autonumber field for the number bit of your ID, then Access takes care of not giving two records the same number. Store the (2-digit) year of registration in a separate text field, and don't necessarily store the Company ID. Just present this as `"E" & [RegYear] & Format([CompanyNo], "00000")` when you need to see it. [CompanyNo] can be your PK.